# How to properly define hash function for a list of objects?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I have a data structure containing a list of objects, like this:

```
class A {
  private List<Object> list;
}
```

How to properly define a hash function for the list, assuming each element of the list has a correct `hashCode()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the actual `List` implementation is fully conformant to the interface, the provided `hashCode` implementation should be sufficient:

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:

```
  hashCode = 1;
  Iterator i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      Object obj = i.next();
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
  }
```

([List documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29))

The `List` interface requires conforming implementations to provide [`equals`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) based on the elements of the list. Thus, they had to specify the `hashCode` algorithm explicitely

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to define `hashCode` for your list, when it [already has it implemented](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29) (along with `equals`)?

(Provided it is `java.util.List` of course - however if not, the link above shows you the exact implementation you can use for your own list type.)

Answer (score 0):

The hash code of a list is defined by the [List interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) of List. This can be used as part of your object's hash code, though there are a couple of cases where you might not want to use it - if the elements of your list have an expensive hash code function, or if the list can hold a reference to the object, and you would then get a stack overflow if the list's algorithm was used. In that case, just use the length of the list or another hash value.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java library, `List` implementations (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList`)  use the default `hashCode` implementation provided by `AbstractList`. which is defined as:

```
int hashCode = 1;
Iterator<E> i = iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    E obj = i.next();
    hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
}
return hashCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why you just wouldn't do:

```
Arrays.hashCode(<cast list to array>);
```

Something like:

```
Arrays.hashCode((String []) myList.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question should have been "how to compute a hashcode of an object containing a list".

```
class A {
  private List<Object> list;
  
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return list.hashCode();
  }

  // ... don't forget to implement custom equals ...
}
```